# How to implement ui:inpuText Enter key event in Lightning

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, aura

How can i implement uiLinpuText **Enter key Event** in Lightning? what i want is when the user done inputing a value into a lightning textbox the **(ui:inputText)** , the user will just press the enter key in the keyboard and will execute a client side controller function().

HERE IS MY CODE

LIGHTNING COMPONENT

```
 <input aura:id="textsearch" 
        type="text" 
        name="default" 
        placeholder="Search Events..." 
        onkeyup="{!c.searchEvents}" 
        class="size-full ht-44 plm prx pvm input input--default input--ph-1 input--focus-1" />
```

CLIENT SIDE CONTROLLER

```
searchEvents: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('Entered');
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the keyCode from the event object .Below is what I tried and worked

```
({
  searchEvents: function(component, event, helper) {
      console.log(event.getParams().keyCode);
      if(event.getParams().keyCode == 13){
        alert('Enter key pressed');
      }
   }
 })
```

You can also use which as well .Below is the console.log of whole event object

[image]

Comment: Does this approach still work for you? I get `[event.getParams is not a function]`.

Comment: Depends on tag you are using ?

Comment: Could you add the code as a gist that's not working ?

Comment: I'm just binding an `onkeyup` event to an `input` tag, same as the OP. I'm able to reference `event.keyCode` but there is no `event.getParams()` function. Maybe it's a versioned change. Seems like it'd be best to just post a new question.

Comment: event.getParams().keyCode
does it work with lightning:input ? if not, what's the alternative way?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a lightning code sample. I tried it in an org that has Winter 16 Release deployed.

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:Attribute name='val' type = 'String' />
    <ui:inputText value='{!v.val}' keyup="{!c.search}" />
</aura:application>

({
    search : function(component, event, helper) {
        if(event.getParams().keyCode == 13){
          alert('Enter key pressed');
            // Do your work here
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: how to prevent user entering key using event.preventDefault()